# Powershell Invoke-RestMethod not authenticated with PAT for Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to invoke the REST API of our Azure DevOps project, and I'm getting some results I don't expect.

I can get results using LinqPad, but using Powershell fails.

### My Script

```
$env:Build_BuildId = 2468
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("myPAT"))
$env:System_TeamProject = "myProject"

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/myorg/$env:System_TeamProject/_apis/build/builds/$env:Build_BuildId/changes?api-version=5.0"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{ 
    Authorization = "Basic $token" 
}

Write-Host $response
```

### The Response

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">




<html lang="en-US">
<head><title>

            Azure DevOps Services | Sign In

</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11;&#32;IE=10;&#32;IE=9;&#32;IE=8" />
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/favicon.ico"/>

    <link data-bundlelength="508485" data-bundlename="commoncss" data-highcontrast="/_static/tfs/M154_20190628.18/_cssbundles/HighContrast/vss-bundle-commoncss-vAEI_yKFIiS9jTVmCtAOiwe4cLPqdXnp6QCUVseU7jzk=" data-includedstyles="jQueryUI-Modified;Core;Splitter;PivotView" href="/_static/tfs/M154_20190628.18/_cssbundles/Default/vss-bundle-commoncss-vqjKBNZxfVQkGGn0rrvF7eh9DJDj__wqtFN85fVrIQn8=" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-bundlelength="116162" data-bundlename="viewcss" data-highcontrast="/_static/tfs/M154_20190628.18/_cssbundles/HighContrast/vss-bundle-viewcss-v356iHjTFccxhkNidRJIEefQ92VqpWpa7rO4mdtAnDpM=" data-includedstyles="VSS.Controls" href="/_static/tfs/M154_20190628.18/_cssbundles/Default/vss-bundle-viewcss-vXHgBtK2hntEJYzWnMNhcJkJC-nUhp2m3BtF-jVlzOZA=" rel="stylesheet" />
... etc. etc.
```

I imagine that the request is given a response that would be rendered by a browser to be the signin landing page for azure devops.

[image]

I have double and triple checked my PAT and even create a few new full access versions w/ no change in behavior.

---

Ultimately this script is going to be run on the hosted agent, so I'm not too worried about this in the end, but I would like to not run the pipeline for testing the script if I don't need to.

Comment: Looks like you're not encoding th PAT properly.  As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/pats?view=azure-devops), it should be something like this: `[Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$PersonalAccessToken)))`.  The `$user` parameter is typically blank,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("myPAT"))` is incorrect. `myPAT` should have a leading colon.

Ex:

```
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":myPAT"))
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using powershell, azure devops, and getting the azure devops sign in html response / return, here's a working solution -

(note: you can replace projectId with a project name and repoId with a repo name)

```
$personalToken = "your pat token"
$patToken = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
$repoHeader = @{"Authorization"="Basic $patToken"}
Write-Output $repoHeader
$projectId = "your project id here"
$repoId = "your repo id here"
$orgName = "your org name here"
$repoUrl = [string]::Format("https://dev.azure.com/{0}/{1}/_apis/git/repositories/{2}/refs?api-version=6.0", $orgName, $projectId, $repoId)
Write-Output $repoUrl
$output = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $repoUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8; api-version=6.0" -Headers $repoHeader -MaximumRedirection 10
Write-Output $output
foreach ($outputValue in $output.value)
{
    Write-Output $outputValue.name
    Write-Output "Hi"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too was hitting this issue following [Etienne Tremblay's "How to use the Azure DevOps REST API with PowerShell"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylJmee-4KTo), which is fantastic, and the only way I was able to get this to work was by using the following for my header:

```
$header = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))
}
```